# Ребят по стеку вызовов подскажите (setTimout) js

Tags: javascript, settimeout

Проблема в том, что после того как курсор покинул блок срабатывает `clear`, но запущенные таймеры (которые уже в стеке) не отменяются, как с таким бороться ?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
document.addEventListener('mouseover', (e) => {
  if (e.target.className == 'bg_game1' ||
    e.target.className == 'bg_game2' ||
    e.target.className == 'bg_game3' ||
    e.target.className == 'bg_page1' ||
    e.target.className == 'bg_page2') {
    moveSlide(e.target)
  }
})

function moveSlide(target) {
  let del = 400;
  let move = 0;

  for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {


    timer(target, del, move)

    del += 400;
    move += -110;
  }
}

let tim;

function timer(target, del, move) {
  tim = setTimeout(() => {
    target.style.left = move + 'px';
    console.log('timeOut')
  }, del);

  document.addEventListener('mouseout', (e) => {
    if (e.target.className == 'bg_game1' ||
      e.target.className == 'bg_game2' ||
      e.target.className == 'bg_game3' ||
      e.target.className == 'bg_page1' ||
      e.target.className == 'bg_page2'
    ) {
      clearTimeout(tim);;
      console.log('clear')
    }
  })
}
```

Comment: если, что это спрайты, которые хочу по наведению передвигать с дилеем.

Comment: создайте работающий пример

Comment: Немного сократил, но и предыдущий работал

Comment: создайте в вопросе работающий пример

Comment: Заголовок должен содержать краткую суть темы, а не крик души...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В данном примере переменная `tim` хранит значение только последнего таймера, потому при `mouseout`, отменяется только последний объявленный таймер. Если я правильно понял Вашу задачу Вам нужно удалять предыдущий объявленный таймер в начале функции `timer`:

```
function timer(target, del, move) {
  if(tim){
    clearTimeout(tim);
  }
  tim = setTimeout(() => {
    target.style.left = move + 'px';
    console.log(del, move)
  }, del);
}
```

Comment: Привет спасибо за помощь, но с таким подходом у меня слайд не делает больше одного шага.
Немного подредактировал код и скинул скрин, там видно , что когда провожу быстро курсором по элементам у них должен очищаться таймаут, после того как курсор вышел из элемента, а они все равно делают по одному таймауту.